# Compare two hashes, then delete if ID not present

Tags: ruby, hash, compare

I have two hashes, one looks like this:

```
{:id => "SG_5viWPcG0SLvszXbBxogLkT_51.514568_-0.126244@1300740367",
 :name => "Shellys Shoes",
 :lat => 51.5145683289,
 :lng => -0.1262439936}
```

This is just one record, there are about 80,

The second hash I have is:

```
{"id":"SG_2zNWLdG9147g2ROvNWpDHr_51.512360_0.124480@1300740823",
"lat":51.5123596191,
"lng":-0.1244800016}
```

The hash above is again just one record, however it is a product of the HASH above after going through an API that does not return all the records, only the valid ones, what I want to do is compare the top hash with the bottom one and delete any records that are not present in the bottom hash,

for example if id:SG_5viWPcG0SLvszXbBxogLkT_51.514568_-0.126244@1300740367 is not in the the second hash then delete that record,

I can compare the hashes, but cant see how to delete if ID is not present?

Thanks guys!

edit:
these are the returned values....

```
{"points":[{"id":"SG_75oKOgvgFPLjwmdyAKA2rq_51.512825_-0.124655@1300740283","lat":51.5128250122,"lng":-0.1246550009},{"id":"SG_0Sz9CBF5t70tdAffTKYNSg_51.512360_-0.124388@1300740807","lat":51.5123596191,"lng":-0.1243880019},{"id":"SG_2zNWLdG9147g2ROvNWpDHr_51.512360_-0.124480@1300740823","lat":51.5123596191,"lng":-0.1244800016},{"id":"SG_5PvBx89sLPgplapegVJDFv_51.513100_-0.124809@1300740049","lat":51.5130996704,"lng":-0.1248089969},{"id":"SG_4luyHFi5R2f1w3cpjT61ik_51.513393_-0.124556@1300740719","lat":51.5133934021,"lng":-0.1245559976},{"id":"SG_4luyHFi5R2f1w3cpjT61ik_51.513393_-0.124556@1300740719","lat":51.5133934021,"lng":-0.1245559976},{"id":"SG_0pEvrpt7bs42jPAxFSrquC_51.512264_-0.124413@1300740807","lat":51.5122642517,"lng":-0.1244129986},]}
```

This is the original format:

```
[ {         :id => "SG_2Km6LX3tEcFwx24eotTHIY_51.513016_-0.123721@1300740411",
            :name => "French Connection Group Plc",
             :lat => 51.5130157471,
             :lng => -0.1237210035
}]
```

Comment: When you say you have about 80 records, are these in an array/list of hashes?

Comment: hey I will edit above to show! thanks!

Comment: The returned values are in JSON format, you need to parse it to use it as hash.

Comment: hey i have done that! thanks! sorry1

Answer (score 0):

You can collect a list of the valid IDs from the returned values with something like:

```
valid_ids = returned["points"].collect { |point| point["id"] }
```

You can then remove the invalid values from the original with something like:

```
original.delete_if { |entry| !valid_ids.include? entry[:id] }
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error with the delete_if 
igeolise.rb:58:in `[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
 from igeolise.rb:58:in `block in <main>'
 from igeolise.rb:58:in `delete_if'
 from igeolise.rb:58:in `<main>'

Comment: The `delete_if` above assumes that `original` is an array of hashes. Sounds like the entries in `original` are arrays and not hashes leading to the error you're seeing when `[:id]` is used as an index into an array (that only has `Integer` indexes). Doublecheck the format of the original, this should work if the original is as currently posted in the question.